# Install add_subdirectory(A) header files before building add_subdirectory(B)

Tags: cmake

I am new to cmake and I am trying to build my code on UNIX and Windows platforms. I have `add_subdirectory(A)` and `add_subdirectory(B)`. If I build only `add_subdirectory(A)`, it installs headers files to some `xyz` location and next when I build `add_subdirectory(B)`, it uses headers files from previously installed `xyz` location. But when I try to build both `add_subdirectory(A)` and `add_subdirectory(B)` together, it fails with missing header files from `xyz` location, as they are not installed. So my question is, is there a way that I can tell cmake to build and install `add_subdirectory(A)` and then start building `add_subdirectory(B)`.

I tried to look online but no luck.

My master **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory(TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/cpp/src)
add_subdirectory(TradeFlowCommonDataLib/cpp/src)

install(EXPORT Findfotmc DESTINATION ${INSTALL_FOTMC}/cmake)

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: " is there a way that I can tell cmake to build and install `add_subdirectory(A)` and then start building `add_subdirectory(B)`." - No, *install* step always comes after *build* step for all components. You may build and install subproject `A` using [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html) CMake command: this command is executed on the *configuration* step, which prepends *build* step for all components.

Answer (score 0):

Adding subdirectories does not specify dependancies between them. You have to explicitly link your second executable/library to your first library.

In the sub CMakeLists of your B project (TradeFlowCommonDataLib/cpp/src) you have to add something like this :

```
target_link_libraries(B A)
```

Comment: Yes I have added target_link_libraries(B A), but it complains about missing header files. To be more clear my add_subdirectory(A) has directory structure like TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/cpp/src where all my headers are in but my add_subdirectory(B) complains about missing header files from TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/header.h, which is different than  TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/cpp/src. So I wanted to install all headers from TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/cpp/src to  TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib for add_subdirectory(A) before building add_subdirectory(B).

Comment: Did you try to add include_directories(TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/cpp/src) in your B's CMakeLists in addition to target_link_library?

Comment: Thanks for your timely response. I did add include_directories(TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/cpp/src) in my B's CMakeLists. It gives me below errorfatal error: TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/TMCommonTypes.h: No such file or directory
 #include "TradeFlowCommonFrameworkLib/TMCommonTypes.h"

Comment: My issue is something similar to https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-December/059248.html. Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: And do you actually have the file in the indicated path (in the case you build only A project I mean) Maybe changing your include to only "TMCommonTypes.h" will work. Did you try this?

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the content of your sub cmakelists?